# Один обработчик срабатывает для нескольких компонентов React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Есть два компонента: родительский и дочерний.
Дочерний компонент (запоминает текст в числовом поле ввода):

```
export class Child extends Component {    
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            value: 0,
        }    
    }

    changeValue(value) {
        this.setState({ value: value });
    }

    render() {
        return (
                <InputNumber
                 onChange={()=>this.changeValue()}
                step={0.1}
                value={this.state.value}/>
        );
    }
}
```

Родительский (отрисовывает просто 2 экземпляра дочернего компонента Child):

```
render()
{
  return(
     <Child/>
     <Child/>
   );
}
```

Так вот, в родительском компоненте есть 2 дочерних компонента, одного вида. Если я в поле ввода (Child 1) что-то введу, то значение сохранится в поле Child 1, но И ТАКЖЕ значение изменится и во втором дочернем компоненте (Child 2). Т.е. изменяя значение в одном поле, оно меняется и в остальных таких же полях. Как побороть и из-за чего такое происходит? Спасибо.

Comment: Что такое InputNumber?

Answer (score 0):

См коменты. 
+ рабочий вариант в [песочнице](https://codesandbox.io/s/determined-mahavira-f5m1w)

```
export class Child extends Component {    
constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
        value: 0,
    }    
}

//здесь эвент приходит
changeValue(event) {
    this.setState({ value: event.target.value });
}

render() {
    return (
            <InputNumber
             //вы эвент не передаете
             onChange={(event)=>this.changeValue(event)}
            step={0.1}
            value={this.state.value}/>
    );
}
```

}